# Авторизация в доменной сети

Tags: авторизация, active-directory, php

Требуется сделать возможной авторизацию в веб-приложении (на php) в сети с контроллером домена БЕЗ участия пользователя (без ввода пары логин/пароль).
Веб-сервер предпочтительно nginx.
Хотелось бы узнать какие есть варианты для этого.

У меня были следующие идеи:

- NTLM (поддерживают все современные браузеры)
- Kerberos (где-то видел, механизм не представляю)
- Плагин к браузеру (никогда не писал ничего подобного, вариантов не видел)
- Проверка через запрос к AD кто сидит за определенным IP (тут много вариантов, легко можно поломать)
- Программа, обеспечивающая авторизацию (не писал такого, видел реализацию, сам не писал, готовой программы не видел)

Comment: Теме нужны свежие ответы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ключевые слова - ldap, ntml
и все это будет работать скорее всего только под IE

Comment: не скорее всего, а ТОЛЬКО в IE. Библиотеку Ldap мучайте.

Comment: просто тоже сталкивалась с этой проблемой, но в глубине души надеялась, что может быть есть какой-то плагин у FF, например? :)

Comment: Мамонты вы)) ntlm уже давно и FF и Opera и Chrome поддерживает. Я ковырял в этом направлении, но ntlm поддерживается только на apache.

Comment: а другой веб-сервер, кроме apache я б и не советовал использовать

Answer (score 0):

Авторизация по MAC адресу если в локальной сети))